# How to parse xml data correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have action which creating a payment and I need to redirect user to complete Payment. I used Pay API operation.

In Pay API it is said that:

```
        You must redirect the sender to PayPal to complete the payment
```

But what is exact url ? Where I should redirect user in development and in production ?

Here is my controller:
}

**EDIT**

```
 @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)
 payKey = @xml['payKey']
 redirect_to "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey="+payKey.to_s()
```

From logs **ERROR**:

```
    Redirected to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payme
     nt&paykey=["AP-7FC15543VK133501B"]
    Completed 302 Found in 1780ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   [2012-07-18 20:01:53] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=["AP-7FC15543VK133501B"]
```

**So I need to delete [""], yes ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per page 70 of the [Adaptive Payments guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf), you'll need to redirect them to https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=value where 'value' is the payKey.

The equivalent URL for the sandbox (development) environment is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=value

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm so inattentive.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=? The *buyer* should be redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=value